# flexslider not showing all of the pictures

Tags: php, jquery, flexslider

I'm using a flexslider as my slideshow, it seems to be working however it is not picking up all of the images.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(window).load(function() {
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     animationLoop: true,
     slideshow: true,
     startAt:0,
     initDelay:0,
     randomize: true

     });
  });

 </script>
 
   <div class="flexslider">     
      <ul class="slides"> 
        <?php           
       foreach ($dataAttachments as $attachment) {
        ?> 
                  <li>    
              <img src="<?php echo Calling the image directory;  ?>" />
             </li> 
        
        <?php
    

            } ?>
     
     </ul>
        </div>
```

That is how I have the code so far. Is there something that I could be missing?

Comment: <img src="<?php echo Calling the image directory;  ?>" />  ,Here are you getting image path?

Comment: Yes... I'm getting the image path that contains more than 1 image.

Comment: Tell <img src="<?php echo Calling the image directory;  ?>" /> What output its giving in browser?

Comment: put your script code after the HTML DIV

Comment: That would be the chrome browse

Comment: I did move the script code after the html div, and I'm still getting the same issue.